# How can I use inches instead of centimetres for page size in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

How can I change Libreoffice page size to inches?

I tried changing the language using **Tools > Language** and set  it all to English(USA) but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Writer select *Tools* -> *Options* -> *LibreOffice Writer* -> *General* and change the *Measurement unit* to Inch. The navigation to change the Measurement unit is similar in LibreOffice Calc and LibreOffice Impress, etc.

[image]

Save the open document to make the change in the Measurement unit permanent.

When you select *File* -> *Print* -> *Options* tab it looks like this.

[image]